# need help adding external files to a combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My use case is you select the combo box and it has a list of bin files from the drop down menu. You select one then click on the button to send the bin file. How do I get the bin files to come with my program in a separate folder?

Comment: what does ps4 have to do with your question??

Comment: its a c# win form app for ps4

Comment: The tags are only for specifically what the question is about. If you're not asking about Visual Studio, then remove that tag. If you're not asking about PS4, then remove that tag. As it stands this question may be too broad - Do you need help adding file names to a combo box? or detecting which one was selected? or copying the selected file to another location?

Comment: well this is all related to ps4 and vs its a ps4 program coded in c# using vs, now i need help making the combo box select the bin file that is located in the payloads folder of my  program in other words when im done it should look like this: http://prntscr.com/kx8llc

and this is my code i am to execute from: SendPayload (string IP, String payloadPath)

Comment: Nothing in the question stated above is specific to PS4 or Visual Studio. They may seem related since your application interacts with PS4 and you're using VS as a code editor, but tags should only be related to the *specific* question you're asking (which I think would be "combobox" and maybe "getfiles"). I think the reason for this is that some people follow specific tags that they're interested in, and it wastes people's time reading questions that are not actually about what the tag says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is, *"How do I add a list of file names from a specific directory to a combobox?"*, then you can use the `Directory.GetFiles(pathToGetFilesFrom)` method to get an array of file names (including the full path), and you can use the `Items.AddRage()` method to add them to your `ComboBox`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = @"f:\public\temp";

    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(filePath));
}
```

Or if you just want to add the file names without the full path, then you could extract them with `Path.GetFileName()`:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory
    .GetFiles(filePath)
    .Select(fullPath => Path.GetFileName(fullPath))
    .ToArray());
```

Comment: im trying to make a ps4 rtm tool a program that reads and sends memory between the ps4 and pc  and it uses payloads the bin files (binary) and so i want to make my program have a folder with it called payloads and then have the bin files in that folder and the combo box reads the named bin files and when selected and i click send it executes the code, the code im using is set as example like this: SendPayload (string IP, String payloadPath) but ive seen in other programs do what im asking

Comment: this is what im looking for: https://prnt.sc/kx8b66 and https://prnt.sc/kx8bdp that should give you a more clear understanding also i dont know what path im supposed to but for var filePath - @"f:\public\temp"; would it be where my file is located i.e: @"f:\dekstop\ps4tool" ?

Comment: No, the path in my sample was just one I used from my machine for testing. Are you saying you don't know how to create a path? I thought this was about loading files from a path into a combo box. Remember questions here need to be very specific (but you can ask more than one, just not in the same question). Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: im stuck on what you said first loading files to the combo box. i want to load the bin files to the combo box that way when you open my program you can select from the combobox which bin(payload) file you want and then click send, i have the code to send it but i dont get this part SendPayload (string IP, *String payloadPath*) <--- string payload path.

*=i dont understand

so if i can load files to the combobox then i could use the path that its using on the sendpayload code so yes idk how to create a path im still very new to this sorta its been like 4 years since ive code c#

Comment: My answer is for the question, "how do I load file paths from a directory into a combo box?". If you have another question, like "how do I create a folder for my application to use?", or "how do I find an existing folder relative to my application install path?" then please ask a new question! :)